# Array conversion guidance

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm stuck on an assignment which converts contents of an array (input from the user) to a pre-declared shorthand.

I want it to be as simple as strcpy(" and ", "+");
to change the word 'and' within a string, to a '+' sign.

Unfortunately, no matter how I structure the function; I get a deprecated conversion warning (variant loops, and direct applications, attempted).

Side note; this is assignment based, so my string shortcuts are severely limited, and no pointers (I've seen several versions of clearing the fault using them).

I'm not looking for someone to do my homework; just guidance on how strcpy can be applied without creating the dep. warning.  Perhaps I shouldn't be using strcpy at all?

Comment: Can you provide your code so far? And an example of the input array?

Comment: you describe _replace_, not copy.  `String x = "this and that"; x.replace("and","+"); Serial.println(x);`

Comment: This is purely a programming question, not an Arduino question. VTC.

Comment: `no pointers ` -- an array *is* a pointer, so how does that work? Is that imposed by your lecturer, or is it just a personal preference?

Comment: You can not access an array without pointers in C++.  This is a question for stackoverflow not here, but it will get closed on there unless you provide more details.  Post a copy of your function and the errors.

Comment: My apologies for the inappropriate post; stackoverflow has been less than helpful, and this site has provided much better guidance overall.  I posted before fully reviewing post preferences, and will avoid inappropriate posts in the future.

Comment: This question is outside of the scope of the Arduino Stack Exhcange ([detailed here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). It would rather suit the Stack Overflow site.

Comment: Is this about Arduino programming? If so then include that as a tag (the arduino c++ compiler does not support a lot of Standard C++ features)

Comment: char conversion()
{char sentence[SIZE];
 char nsentence[SIZE];
 int i;
 int senti = 0;
 int nsenti = 0;
 bool same = true;

 do {
  if(sentence[senti] == 'A' | sentence[senti] == 'a')
   same = true;
  else if(sentence[senti + 1] != 'N' | sentence[senti + 1] != 'n') //toupper
   same = false;
  else if(sentence[senti + 2] != 'D' | sentence[senti + 2] != 'd')
   same = false;
   if(same)    {
      same = "+";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen("And"); i++)    {
     nsentence[nsenti + i] = sentence[senti + i];
    }
   }
 }while(senti != strlen(sentence));
 return 0;
}

Comment: UGH, guidance on posting code is needed too apparently, so sorry.

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy` copies the contents of the second string into the memory of the first string. Since you're copying a string literal into a string literal it can't do it (you can't write to a string literal) and so it complains.

Instead you need to build your own search and replace system. You can use `strstr()` to search for a substring within a string, and it returns the pointer in memory to the start of that found string (if it's found).

Let's take the sample string `Jack and Jill went up the hill`.

```
char *andloc = strstr(buffer, " and ");
```

That would return the address of the start of the string (say `0x100`) plus the offset of the word " and " (including spaces) within it (`0x100 + 4`) which would be `0x104`.

Then, if found, you can replace it with the `&` symbol. However you can't use `strcpy` for that as it'll terminate the string. Instead you can set the bytes manually, or use memcpy:

```
if (andloc != NULL) { // it's been found
    andloc[1] = '&';
    andloc[2] = ' ';
}
```

or:

```
if (andloc != NULL) { // it's been found
    memcpy(andloc, " & ", 3);
}
```

That would result in `Jack & d Jill went up the hill`. We're not quite there yet. Next you have to shuffle everything down to cover the "d " from the old " and ". For that you'd think you could now use `strcpy` or `memcpy`, however that's not possible - the strings (source and destination) overlap, and the manual pages for both specifically state that the strings must not overlap and to use `memmove` instead.

So you can move the contents of the string after the "d " to after the "& " instead:

```
memmove(andloc + 3, andloc + 5, strlen(andloc + 5) + 1);
```

Adding a number to a string like that adds to the address of the pointer. So we're looking at copying the data from 5 characters further on in the string that the old "and" location into a space starting at 3 characters on from the start of the old "and" location. The amount to copy is the length of the string from 5 characters on from the start of the "and" location plus one so it copies the NULL character at the end of the string.

Another manual way of doing it would be to iterate through each character until you find the end of the string:

```
char *to = andloc + 3;
char *from = andloc + 5;
while (*from) { // Until the end of the string
    *to = *from; // Copy one character
    to++;        // Move to the ...
    from++;      // ... next character pair
}
*to = 0; // Add the end of string marker.
```

So now either way the string memory contains:

```
Jack & Jill went up the hill\0l\0
```

The `\0` is the end of string marker, so the actual string "content" is only up as far as the first `\0` and the `l\0` is now ignored.

Note that this only works if you are replacing a part with something that is smaller. If you are replacing it with something bigger, so the string grows in size, you will be forced to use `memmove`, which first copies the content to a scratchpad, and ensure that your buffer has enough room in it to store the finished string (this kind of thing is often a big source of "buffer overruns" which are a security headache and one of the biggest causes of systems being hacked). Also you have to do the whole thing backwards - move the latter part of the string first to make room, then modify the gap between the two halves.

Comment: Thank you for guidance, but some of this was still beyond the assignment parameters.  I worked with what was permitted...and it helped me progress a lot.  Thank you.

Here is the conversion prototype so far (for piece "And" to "+"); it is not giving me an output, and I'm uncertain of next steps.  Is there an update step I should take, and if so, I'm unsure what it would look like.

Comment: And what exactly are the assignment parameters?

Comment: char conversion()
{
 char sentence[SIZE];
char nsentence[SIZE];
int i;
 int senti = 0;
 int nsenti = 0;
 bool same = true;

 do
 {
  if(sentence[senti] == 'A' | sentence[senti] == 'a')
   same = true;
  else if(sentence[senti + 1] != 'N' | sentence[senti + 1] 
= 'n') //toupper
   same = false;
  else if(sentence[senti + 2] != 'D' | sentence[senti + 2] != 'd')
   same = false;
   if(same)
   {
    same = "+";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen("And"); i++)
    {
     nsentence[nsenti + i] = sentence[senti + i];
    }
   }
 }while(senti != strlen(sentence));

Comment: return nsentence[nsenti];
}

Comment: What is that supposed to be?

Comment: Parameters are to only use what was taught before assignment; which was limited to arrays, and array manipulation, with no use of string library outside of strlen, strcpy.  I know pointers, and want to use them, but this is pre-scope for the "simple" assignment